# setting background in plot()

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, vector-graphics

I am trying to plot a CDF to display water quality data relative to water quality standards.

To make the water quality standards apparent I am using `rect()` to indicate which parts of the plot are not within the set standards.

I am using density within `rect()` to create a hashed fill so that it will work better when printed in black and white (and I think it looks better).

This works fine when I only have one area of the plot I want to use `rect()`:

[image: one_rect() in plot]

When I have two separate `rect()` calls in the plot the first `rect()` seems to ignore the density argument and uses a solid fill:

[image: two_rect in plot]

Here is an example of the code I used to do this:

Data for pH

```
data<-rnorm(30, mean = 7, sd = 1)
```

plot for pH

```
data.ecdf<-ecdf(data)
plot(data.ecdf, verticals = TRUE, do.points = FALSE, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", xlim=c(5,10), panel.first = rect(5, -0.02, 6, 1.04, density = 20, border = "258", col = "258"))

plot(data.ecdf, verticals = TRUE, do.points = FALSE, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", xlim=c(5,10), panel.first = rect(5, -0.02, 6, 1.04, density = 20, border = "258", col = "258", rect(9,-0.02,10,1.04, density = 20, border = "258", col = "258")))
```

I also tried to do this in ggplot2 but it seems getting a hashed fill is much more difficult than in graphics.

Any thoughts or ideas on how I can get both `rect()`'s in the background to display with a hashed fill (`density = 20`) would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it's happening, but you can call both rectangles at once within the `panel.first` arg:

```
plot(data.ecdf, verticals = TRUE, do.points = FALSE, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", xlim=c(5,10), panel.first = c(
  rect(9,-0.02,10,1.04, density = 20, border = "258", col = "258"),
  rect(5, -0.02, 6, 1.04, density = 20, border = "258", col = "258")
))
```

Alternatively, try calling the rectangles independently as layers:

```
plot(data.ecdf, verticals = TRUE, do.points = FALSE, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", xlim=c(5,10), lty='n')
rect(9,-0.02,10,1.04, density = 20, border = "258", col = "258")
rect(5, -0.02, 6, 1.04, density = 20, border = "258", col = "258")
lines(data.ecdf, verticals = TRUE, do.points = FALSE, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", xlim=c(5,10))
```

[image]